# Two Ethernet cards (different subnet) and unable to ping eth1

Tags: linux, networking, subnet

I have been trying to solve this problem in weeks but am unable to do so.

I am running RHEL5.3 and have two network interfaces (dhcp). I'm having problems accessing eth0 via ping or ssh when i'm in the same subnet (if eth1 is unplugged, eth0 becomes alive).

Here is my interface configuration.

```
    [root@new ~]# ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:55:34:BB
              inet addr:10.65.71.94  Bcast:10.65.71.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::226:b9ff:fe55:34bb/64 Scope:Link
    eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:55:34:BD
              inet addr:192.168.1.33  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::226:b9ff:fe55:34bd/64 Scope:Link

    [root@new ~]# ip route show
    192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.33
    10.65.71.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.65.71.94
    192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
    169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link
    default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
    [root@new ~]#
```

Please help!

Comment: Your subject says eth0 is the problem, and the body says eth1. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Offhand, I'd say that it is because you have 2 gateways configured in the NIC config. Everytime I have seen this sort of behavior, I've found that both NICs have a configured gateway (and if both are DHCPing their IPs then they probably do).

Statically configure one of these NICs, and don't assign a gateway, and see if everything works.